# Truncate an array in a specified dimension in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, does a `pad` command exist, which also pads in the negative dimension
(therefore removing indices in a specified dimension)?

[Edit: I knew something did this - `fft` does this for the input, but it also takes the `fft` first.]

I have a function which can receive input data `x` in `n_dim` dimensions.

I would like to remove all but `n` datapoints from a user specified dimension `dim`.
I could use `shiftdim` to always make the specified dimension the first dimension;
however, how do I code such that I do not need a finite number of colons
to represent the dimensions of the input data `x`?

```
x   = rand(01,12,01); % n_dim = 1  
y   = rand(04,12,01); % n_dim = 2  
z   = rand(04,12,07); % n_dim = 3

n   = 3
```

see:

```
dim = 1
y = y(1:n, :    );
z = z(1:n, :, : ); % Note that extra colons are needed depending on n_dim.
```

or:

```
dim = 2

x = x(   1:n    );
y = y(:, 1:n,   );
z = z(:, 1:n, : ); % Note that extra colons are needed depending on n_dim.
```

Do I need to use the `shiftdim` command to place `dim` in the first dimension,
and then place the `1:n` within the `eval` command
along with a `string` variable which contains as many `,:`s as needed?

Comment: `eval` does not work with these comma's and semicolons, because it really evaluates the statement in the string.  Similiar to if you tell matlab `1:n,:,:`, it will just throw an error.

Comment: For the shifting of dimensions I would indeed use `shiftdim`. You can use it like this `OutputMatrix = shiftdim(InputMatrix,dim-1);` Then apply your operations on OutputMatrix: `OutputMatrix = shiftdim(OutputMatrix,n_dims-(dim-1));`

Comment: @BramMooij : Yeah, but I could create a for loop or something similar which adds as many `,:` as necessary to the eval string.

Comment: Did you find a solution?